# How to show that the following two terms are identically distributed?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I'm looking to show that the two terms described at the bottom are identically distributed, but I'm not sure how to show this:

Denoting by $\in_R$ a random uniform choice from a set, let:

$A\in_{R} \mathbb{Z}^{m\times n}_q$

$ r \in_{R} \{0,1\}^m$

$ l, s \in_{R} \{0,1\}^n$

$ k \in_R \{0,1\}$

Then the following are identically distributed:

$$ (r^T A +\frac{q}{2} l, r^T A s+\frac{q}{2}k) $$
$$ (r^T A, r^T A s) $$

How can I accomplish this? (if at all possible -I only have a vague intuition that this should be correct, but cannot formally show this).

Comment: Why the close vote? I am looking for assistance in a topic that is not my strongest suit and would really appreciate some advice. Is there anything missing? I would have inserted some attempt, except I really do not know how to approach this formally.